# Can't sign into Google using Google plugin for Eclipse

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

I am using Eclipse Luna and I recently installed the Google plugin for Eclipse to deploy apps to the Google app engine.

I tried signing into Google services and was able to get past the password prompt and 2-step verification screen successfully. After that I get the permissions screen where I click 'Accept'.

[image: Permissions Screen]

After I click 'Accept' however nothing happens and the window goes blank. I've waited for like an hour and yet it just stays like that.

[image: Blank Window]

I have tried using a different Eclipse workspace, a different Eclipse installation (Luna), a different Google account which doesn't have 2-step authentication but I get the same result.

I have even checked the Eclipse log file and there are no entries made at time I tried signing in.

I've searched around but couldn't find anything related to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing same kind of issue. For me accept and cancel buttons are not enabled. Pleas any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Right click, choose another encoding. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with next configuration

- Windows 8.1
- JDK 7 and 8
- Eclipse Luna
- Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.4
- GWT SDK 2.6
- App Engine SDK 1.9

I think that something wrong with Google plugin, so here my Windows command line workaround:

1. Download and install external tools: [App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads), [Apache
   Ant](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi). At moment of writing this text Google App Engine doesn't
   support Java 8, so you need install Java 7 and configure JAVA_HOME
   environment variable accordingly.
2. Add to PATH environment variable paths to bin folders of App Engine and Ant.
3. Run command line and go to folder of your Eclipse project. Note that your project must be configured with Ant and `build.xml` file must be inside your project's folder.
4. Type `ant build` command and wait until successful compilation.
5. Configure your application ID via Eclipse or edit file `war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml` and set appropriate value into `<application>` tag.
6. Type `app cfg update war` It may run your browser, ask you credentials and ask to paste generated key.
7. After successful deploy navigate to `your_application_id.appspot.com`
8. Enjoy.

Read [this article](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html#deploy) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There were some bugs in the oAuth flow when you encountered this. We fixed all the ones we knew about last year. GPE login should be working now, but if not you can also try the newer [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/).

Comment: It is not working for me with Eclipse Neon on Ubuntu. (I am not seeing the permission page.  Got blank after the password prompt.  I have tried turning off 2FA but that didn't help either.)  I also can't use the Cloud Tools because there is a huge change in the way App Engine Java is supported (no data nucleus for example.)  I am kind of stuck right now.

Comment: Is this a returning bug? I got the same problem now (Windows 10, Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.4/4.5/4.6 3.9.6.v20170329-1604)

Comment: Maybe. We (Google Cloud Eclipse team) haven't been able to reproduce it yet, but we are hearing multiple reports. I have a couple of ideas I want to try today to see if I can narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem ( Ubuntu 16.04 LTS )

To solve it I went to Eclipse Market Place and installed Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.1.0

I accepted all the items to be installed

When I finished the installation, I restarted Eclipse, reopened it, clicked the Google icon in the bottom right corner, and logged in to the Chrome browser (It opens Chrome automatically).

This way I managed to make the connection.

I hope this can help !