# can't sign in to google from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using Eclipse Luna on windows 8. Recently I have Google plugins for eclipse to deploy apps to GAE. But i have faced a problem with signing in to google. When i Click "sign in to google" button and after entering my uname and pass the eclipse shows a white window and do nothing.

This Question I asked already but has no answer. [Can't sign into Google using Google plugin for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250547/cant-sign-into-google-using-google-plugin-for-eclipse)

But now after some days it gives me the following error too (due to less reputation i can't post the image) `Error: 'navCancelContainer' is undefined`